# Creating a Common Class to share MenuControls

Tags: c#

I have a program with several different forms, most of these forms have some repetition in them especially when it comes to form manipulation controls. How do I create a common class so I don't have the same code on each form, but am still able to manipulate individual forms. For instance the code below is a ToolStripMenuControl for making the form Always on top. I have this code repeated 4 times in other forms, but I cant seem to wrap my head around how to go about creating a shared control for this. What am I missing here?

```
    public bool onTop = false;
    public bool ToggleTop()
    {
        if (onTop)
        {
            onTop = false;
            this.TopMost = false;
            keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            return onTop;
        }
        if (!onTop)
        {
            onTop = true;
            this.TopMost = true;
            keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            return onTop;
        }
        else return onTop;
    }

    private void keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTop();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough, but considering this toggles a boolean, that would be stored in another class how would I prevent the form from respawning this instance with the boolean set to the default? Just store the boolean on the form referencing the class?

Comment: Also, not that easy since in the above code this.TopMost doesn't refer to a class. Neither does keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store a separate `bool onTop`.  `Form.TopMost` already tracks the exact same value.

For this simple task, your code is too long.  You can rewrite it simply as:

```
public class Form5 : Form {

    CheckBox cbTopMost = new CheckBox { Text = "Top Most" };

    public Form5() {
        Controls.Add(cbTopMost);

        cbTopMost.CheckedChanged += delegate {
            this.TopMost = cbTopMost.Checked;
        };
    }
}
```

If you really want, have all your Forms extend a base form, such as the example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use some base form with common implementation. It means you will move this code to some separate base class and all your forms with this ToolStripMenuControl will derive from it.

```
protected class FormWithToolStripControl : Form
{
    //Initialization of ToolStripControl will be somewhere here

    //And here your common code for all forms derived from this class
    public bool onTop = false;
    public bool ToggleTop()
    {
        if (onTop)
        {
            onTop = false;
            this.TopMost = false;
            keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
            return onTop;
        }
        if (!onTop)
        {
            onTop = true;
            this.TopMost = true;
            keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
            return onTop;
        }
        else return onTop;
    }

    private void keepOnTopToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleTop();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was afraid this might be the case. Since I created all my forms using the VS auto generation this would be more trouble than it's worth. I'd essentially have to rewrite the whole thing and in the end this code might not be replicated but other code would be instead.